Size of non-floating element determines if it wraps the floating element
I doubt how non-floating block elements are positioned with respect to floating elements.
Let's consider the HTML code below. The third div is correctly positioned on the right of the two floating divs.


<section style="width:150px;">
  <div style="float:left; width: 50px;height: 150px;background: pink;border:solid 1px;">3</div>
  <div style="float:left; width: 50px;height: 150px;background: pink;border:solid 1px;">3</div>
  <div style="background: cyan;">3</div>
</section>



If I set the width of the third one, for example
<div style="width:50px;background: cyan;">3</div>

the third div overlaps with the first div. In particular, it goes behind the first one.


<section style="width:150px;">
  <div style="float:left; width: 50px;height: 150px;background: pink;border:solid 1px;">3</div>
  <div style="float:left; width: 50px;height: 150px;background: pink;border:solid 1px;">3</div>
  <div style="width:50px;background: cyan;">3</div>
</section>



Could you explain to me the reason behind that?

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

I edited your question to include a runnable snippet, and the code you provided doesn't seem to match your description. Specifically, in the second snippet, the blue div goes below the other divs, not behind it.

@j08691 thanks. It goes behind. If you change the visibility of the first div you can see the third div behind

@Antonio I see what you mean now. The blue div is obscured by the other divs and only a portion of it is visible, sticking out below it

Floats are taken out of normal flow, but painted later, so the margin boxes¹ of in-flow block level boxes in the same stacking context are painted behind the floats, always.
What matters in your examples is the line box. Is there sufficient space available for the text (i.e. the "3" character) to be shown on alongside the floats? In the first example there is, so the text is displayed there. In the second example, there isn't. so the text is shown on the first line where there is space for it, which is below the floats. The in-flow block box is extended downwards sufficiently to contain the text.

¹ Whether the border box is painted behind the floats depends on whether the in-flow block-level box establishes an independent formatting content or not.
